# Change HTML div element wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, href, elementor

I'm building a website in wordpress. I'm using 'buttons' with padding and an image background for some categories on the homepage.

Right now only the button is clickable.  I would like the whole div (including the image background) to be clickable.

I learned how to change the HTML div to an 'a href' tag, which works (when editing in Google Chrome dev mode.

My struggle, how do I change this HTML code in Wordpress? It works perfectly in Google Chrome dev and I would like to implement it on WP but I can figure out where.

Basically, where and how can I change the HTML for a specific div class in Wordpress?

Many thanks,

Kristian

-Changed the div class in HTML in Google Chrome Dev to an 'a href=""' which works in Chrome dev
-Looked into WP theme editor
-Tried adding html as a snippet and as a block in elementor

Comment: Since you are building a site I assume you are familiar with PHP, therefore all you need to do is find the appropriate template to edit. You should also look into a child theme for your customization.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: @GeorgeP, unfortunately I'm not that familiar with PHP. Started with designing in WP and right now learning more and more about HTML and CSS. Are you able to give a dummy version of what I need to do in the child's PHP file?

Comment: @Kristian What type of button are you doing? Is that a plugin provided button like the "Add to Cart" button from woocommerce or is it a button on a page in the page builder? If you are familiar with the developer console pasting the element code here would likely help us understand how best to help out.

Comment: @speshock apologies for the confusion. It's a normal elementor button I guess. You can see it on www.ontwerpo.nl There are a couple buttons like these on the homepage, but for example the first one, that says 'Woonkamer'

Comment: @Kristian I now realized that you are using a Page Builder (Elementor). Unless you are able to customize that Page Builder and create your own widgets, you are limited to whatever tools it is offering. Look into other widgets that Elementor might have, like cards/banners, that will allow you to put a link to the whole box, and not just a button with a background. Good luck.